# Mocking, virtual and more

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

This question would have been asked many times w.r.t to **RhinoMocks**, but I will try to present a little differently. I have a situation like this below -

```
class A
{
   X parentOfB;
   A()
   { 
       X parentOfB = someObj;
       if(<something>)
       {
         B objB = parentOfB as B  // NOTE THIS 
         if(objB.Foo)            // call the property here
         {
            // some code ....
         }
       }
   }
}
```

---

```
class B : X
{
   // gets initialised to true somewhere in the program. Don't bother much
   protected bool status ;
   B() {}

   // Property
   public bool Foo
   {
     return status;
   }

}
```

---

**Mocking:**
Now, I want to do something like this -

```
var mock = new MockRepository();

var myObjB = mock.StrictMock<B>();

// call Db class to populate the objB object and then set the expectation as 
// below  
// ...
// ...
Expect.Call(myObjB.Foo).Return(true);
mock.ReplayAll();
var objA = new A();
mock.VerifyAll();
```

**Error:**
Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).

Problem is that, the concrete class B is being accessed in ctor of A for accessing the Property. How do I handle this scenario in **RhinoMocks** ? If I make the propeerty Foo as virtual, it works fine. But, I do not want to do that.

Comment: this is to be expected and the error says why: `make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#)` - so try and make Foo virtual!

Comment: Carsten- I am asking for an alternative or a better design for my code. I have mentioned alread - _ If I make the propeerty Foo as virtual, it works fine. But, I do not want to do that._

Comment: You want a better design that is Test/Mockable - easy extract the methods into interfaces and mock these ....

Answer (score 3):

First, check your exception stack trace, and see where the "invalid call" error is coming from. Does it come from the `Expect.Call` line? If so, remove the `A` class from the picture.

Second, all mocking frameworks need a way to check if a property/method has been called. They replace the regular property/method code with some code that records how the call happened. In order to replace code, a mocked property or method must be virtual or abstract, or the mock should be created for an interface.

Comment: Expect.Call(myObjB.Foo).Return(true);. _If I make the property Foo as virtual, it works fine. But, I do not want to do that._

Comment: @SeeSharp, mocks only work by replacing virtual/abstract/interface methods. They need to record calls so that you can write assertions like `Expect.Call`.

Answer (score 0):

If a property needs to be mocked, and its original behaviour can't be mocked away, here's one alternative. You move the code from `B.Foo` into a new property, and create a virtual dummy replacement for `B.Foo`.

```
class B
{
    // Old code here
    public bool RealFoo { get { return status; } }

    // New dummy code
    public virtual bool Foo { get { return RealFoo; } }
}
```

Then from your mocking code, you can record when `Foo` gets called, and you can call the "real" code too:

```
var myObjB = mock.StrictMock<B>();

Expect.Call(myObjB.Foo).Return(myObjB.RealFoo);
```

Comment: But, just for the sake of mocking, injecting something like this in a  production code is not much appreciated.

Comment: @SeeSharp: If you aren't willing to make this sacrifice for the sake of better test coverage, you might need to consider a new strategy for how to test this code (or it will go untested). Realistically, I'd recommend extracting an interface out of `B`, and mocking that. Then test `B.Foo` independently.